# How to create a Supplier from another Supplier and filter out some items?

Tags: java, java-stream, functional-interface

Suppose `Supplier<Optional<Item>>` is the source and `Supplier<Item>` is what we want: the same items without `Optional.Empty` cases.

Comment: What should your supplier return if the optional is empty?

Comment: Please show what code you have attempted.

Comment: Map it to a `Stream.generate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by [Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68778868/how-to-create-a-supplier-from-another-supplier-and-filter-out-some-items#comment121551231_68778868) and [khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68778904/1553851):

```
Supplier<Item> filtered = Stream.generate(optSupplier)
        .flatMap(Optional::stream)
        .iterator()::next;
```

If you're pre-Java 9, replace `flatMap` with `.filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)`.

Answer (score 1):

Given `Supplier<Optional<Item>> optSupplier`:

```
Supplier<Item> itemSupplier = () -> {
    Optional<Item> opt = optSupplier.get();
    while (!opt.isPresent()) {
        opt = optSupplier.get();
    }
    return opt.get();
};
```

When you try to `get` from the item supplier, it will keep pulling from the optional supplier until it gets a result that isn't empty, and then return the item.

(Caveat: If the optional supplier always returns an empty optional, then the item supplier will be stuck in an infinite loop.)

Comment: Thanks @khelwood I have the same solution. looked a bit wired to me.